# Issue with sending data client --> server socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am currently in the process of building my own simple multiplayer game using socket.io and node.js. Currently, two users can connect, and receive the side of the screen they will occupy.

I am trying to have the clients send a packet of data every tick an arrow key is pressed. Either the data is never sending, or is never being received by the server, because nothing about it is output to the server console.

Here is my code as it stands:
(init is called in the intex.html file)

client:

```js
var canvas
var ctx
var side = ""
var theinterval
var keys = []
var RHSpaddley = 200
var LHSpaddley = 200
var side = "null"
var socket

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000", { transports: ["websocket"]});
  setEventHandlers();


}


  function setEventHandlers() {
   // Keyboard
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    });
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
      keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    });

   // Window resize
   //window.addEventListener("resize", onResize, false);
      socket.on("connect", onSocketConnected);
      socket.on("disconnect", onSocketDisconnect);
      socket.on("new player", newPlayer)
      socket.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
      });
      socket.on('start game', startGame)
  };






function onSocketConnected() {
    console.log("Connected to socket server");

};


function onSocketDisconnect() {
    console.log("Disconnected from socket server");
};

function newPlayer(data) {
  console.log("here")
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data.clientsIn
  console.log("clientsin is " + data.clientsIn)
  if(side == "null") {
    if(data.clientsIn == 1) {
    side = "left"
    console.log("side is left")


  } else if(data.clientsIn == 2) {
      side = "right"
      console.log("side is right")



    } else {
    console.log("more than two players dectected")

  }

}


}

function startGame() {
    theinterval = setInterval(main, 1);


}


function main() {
  doKeys()


}
function doKeys() {
    //s
    if(side == "left") {
      console.log("left")
      if(keys[40]) {
        if ((LHSpaddley + 70) <= 400) {
            console.log("sendingmovement")
            socket.emit("LHS")
        }
    }

      //w
      if(keys[38]) {
        if (LHSpaddley >= 0) {
            console.log("sendingmovement")
            socket.emit("LHS")

        }
    }

  }
    if(side == "right") {
      console.log("right")
      if(keys[38]) {
        if (RHSpaddley >= 0) {
            console.log("sendingmovement")
            socket.emit("RHS")
        }
    }

    //down
      if(keys[40]) {
        if ((RHSpaddley + 70) <=400 ) {
            console.log("sendingmovement")
            socket.emit("RHS")
        }
    }



}
}
```

And here is my server side code:

```js
var util = require("util");


var express = require('express');
var app  = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(http);
var clientsIn = 0



//game vars
var LHSpaddley = 200
var RHSpaddley = 200
var WIDTH = 600;
var HEIGHT = 400;
var ballx = 200;
var bally = 200;
var LHSpaddley = 200;
var RHSpaddley = 200;
var changex = 1;
var changey = 1;
var RHSscore = 0;
var LHSscore = 0;
var keys = [];
var hasHit = false;
var theinterval

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

http.listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('listening on port 8000');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));


function init() {
    players = [];
    theinterval = setInterval(getReady, 1)
    util.log("setting event handlers")
    setEventHandlers()


}


init()

function setEventHandlers() {
    socket.sockets.on("connection", onSocketConnection);
    //socket.sockets.on("RHS", RHSmove)
    //socket.sockets.on("LHS", LHSmove)


    socket.sockets.on('message', function (message) {
      console.log(message);
    });
}

function onSocketConnection(client) {

    util.log("New player has connected: "+client.id);
    clientsIn++
    socket.emit("new player", {clientsIn: clientsIn});

    console.log("emitted");

    client.on("disconnect", onClientDisconnect);


}


function onClientDisconnect() {
    util.log("Player has disconnected: "+this.id);

    clientsIn = clientsIn - 1
    socket.sockets.emit("player left");
};


function getReady() {

    if(clientsIn == 2) {
      clearInterval(theinterval)
      socket.sockets.emit("start game")
      console.log("game started")

    }


}


function LHSmove() {
  console.log("LHS")


}

function RHSmove() {

  console.log("RHS")



}
```

Thanks!

--Boi

Comment: Is the `onSocketConnected` method called correctly? Can you confirm that you are connected to the socket server from the client correctly? In other words, make sure that the `init` function is executed correctly and the `socket` variable is initialized properly.

Comment: Yes, when a client connects I get a message in the terminal that a new player has connected. The client can then receive information from the server, just not the other way around.

Comment: Cool! So in the `main` method where you define all the movements, do you see the logs for `sendingmovement` etc in your console? Try logging the entire `socket` object in to your console in the `doKeys` function. If you can confirm that the socket object is correct, try n check the network panel in chrome dev tools, it lets you monitor requests.

Comment: Alright, so I did get sendingmovement out in the console beforehand. I replaced that part of the code with console.log(socket) for each of the four possibilities. I get out 'Socket {io: Manager, nsp: "/", json: Socket, ids: 0, acks: Object…}'. BTW thanks for all the help!

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing I try seems to work.